# Apache2 interpret .ext file as php

Tags: php, apache2

I run apache2 server and I need to make .ext file to be interpreted as php. Here's some details:

os: Debian

php --version result:

```
PHP 7.4.28 (cli) (built: Feb 17 2022 16:17:19) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.28, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

How can I make .ext file interpret as .php file or which additional packages should I install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `AddType application/x-httpd-php .ext` to your main config, virtualhost config, or `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Worked! I had to put it in apache2.conf. .htaccess didnt worked for some reason. Thanks!